# Rotate imageview in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple zoom in/out view.

So I extend the `LinearLayout` and add two `ImaegView` as the `in` and `out` button, this is the codes:

```
public class ZoomView extends LinearLayout{

    private ImageView mZoomIn;
    private ImageView mZoomOut;


    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setupView();
    }

    private void setupView() {
        mZoomIn = new ImageView(getContext());
        mZoomOut = new ImageView(getContext());

        mZoomIn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_zoomin_btn));
        mZoomIn.setOnClickListener(this);

        mZoomOut.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_zoomout_btn));
        mZoomOut.setOnClickListener(this);


        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        } else {
            setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        }
        addView(mZoomIn);
        addView(mZoomOut);
    }
}
```

As the codes shown, I want to `ZoomView` change its orientation according to the screen.

However I just have two images:

Now this is what I get at the `portrait` view(this is what I want):

[image]

However this is for `landscape` view:
[image]

While I want this for `landscape` view:

[image]

Then I wonder if I can implement my requirement without new bit maps? Perhaps rotate the imageview or something else? I have tried:

```
mZoomIn.setRotate(-90);
```

or

```
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(-90);
        mZoomIn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
        mZoomIn.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

But this does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think even if you rotate the zoomOut image -90 angle but minus image will become horizontal means like a horizontal bar `|`. and will not solve your problem for ZoomOut. will work fine for zoomIn though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**mZoomIn's values:**

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
mZoomIn.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.postRotate( -90f, mZoomIn.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2,
mZoomIn.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

**and same for mZoomOut:**

```
 matrix.postRotate( 90f, mZoomOut.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2,
 mZoomOut.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
```

Dont forget to use the `f` in the `90f` or just do a `type casting`
The proper implementation of `matrix.postRotate` is as below:

```
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
```

hope this works out for you.